# How to remove color from the UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

In my application i have using UIWebview.I have clear back ground color of uiWebview.But whrn data is loaded his background will be brown color.but i want to clear back ground.how it is possible?any budy have idea about my question then please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

you can load your html source separately, then change background-color property and then init your webView with loadHTMLString method.